# MongoDB : update entire document except _id using C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to update all the fields except _id. 
I want to avoid to manually update the 16 fields...
All the new fields are stored inside a BsonDocument

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Philipp hinted there is a way way to do this. You can actually use the `save` function ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Save%3CTDocument%3Emethod ) which will do what he says for you in the database end.

So imagine you have a document of:

```
{
    _id: {},
    d: 1
}
```

And that `_id` already exists, it will replace the previous document with this one.

Neat huh?

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to use .Save generalized? I imagine it's quite easy to inject an arbitrary Id value into a document and send it as an http PUT to the server. Without checking if there is an existing document first, the operation can end up as a POST, but without the controller logic of the method behind POST. Without having further information, I use .Update and .Replace with the C# driver.

Comment: @Besrl That is a good point it can be quite dangerous, you should always ensure that the _id of the document is validated and checked by your application logic, along with other things

Comment: There is also the `Update.Replace` builder for cases when you need to do an update, e.g. optimistic concurrency versioning.

Comment: Save() also doesn't work if there are unique indexes on fields besides the _id.

Answer (score 1):

When I understood you correctly, you have a document B with new data and you want it to completely replace document A.

In that case you can just set the _id field of document B explicitely to the value of the _id field of document A. When you then save document B, it will replace document A in the database.

When a saved document has the id of an existing document, the database will treat it like a new version of that document, not as a new document.