# How in mongoDb PHP replace all values except the id in BulkWrite operation?

Tags: php, mongodb, bulkinsert

How in mongoDb PHP replace all values except the id in BulkWrite operation?

Below i tried with simple collection->updateOne(....). 
But the BulkWrite->update does not work too. 
i mostly need BulWrite on the same id, totally new values, because new values is very large nested array, and it does not make sense to set each value explicitly.

This post says that i should set id explicitly among saved values, which should overwrite the previous entity. But this does not work for me. 
[MongoDB : update entire document except _id using C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336116/mongodb-update-entire-document-except-id-using-c-sharp-driver)

```
$mgm = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( "mongodb://localhost:27017" ); // $connectionUri,$connectionOptions
$mgc = new MongoDB\Client();
$mgbw = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();   
$mgc_IS = $mgc->selectCollection( 'db', 'collection', [] ); 

$ust = $mgc_IS->findOne([ 'alias'=> '2121515456' ]);
echo "<br> us!==null" .  ( $ust!==null );
if( $ust!==null ) {
    $_id = $ust->_id;
    var_dump( $ust ); // MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument  // var_dump( $ust->toArray()  will not work on BSONDocument
    $ustA = $ust->getArrayCopy();
    foreach ( $ustA as $k=>$v ) {
        if( is_scalar($v) ) { $ustA[$k]='neValue'; }
        else if ( is_array($v) ) { $ustA[$k] = [ 'a'=>1, 'n'=>2, 'c'=>3 ]; }
    } // foreach ( $ustA as $k=>$v ) 
    $ustA['alias']= '2121515456';
    $ustA['_id']= $_id;
    $ust_id = $mgc_IS->updateOne( [ '_id'=>$_id ] , [ '$set'=>$ustA], [ 'multi' => false, 'upsert' => true ] ); 
    $ust2 = $mgc_IS->findOne([ 'alias'=>'2121515456' ]);  
    var_dump( $ust2 ); //contains the same objcet  + new values 
} // if($ust!==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i am sorry for the question, seems was tired.
In order to replace all values except id, one shall use replace method. Replacement operations are similar to update operations, but instead of updating a document to include new fields or new field values, a replacement operation replaces the entire document with a new document, but retains the original document’s _id value.

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#replace-documents 
https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-bulkWrite/index.html

```
MongoDB\Collection::replaceOne
MongoDB\Collection::findOneAndReplace
MongoDB\Collection::bulkWrite( [[ 'replaceOne' => [ $filter, $replacement, $options ] ], ]);
```

And this article by Alex Tatulchenkov (2016) is very helpful:
https://medium.com/@webtota/php7-and-mongodb-madness-148cfc30bc5b